# Getting a value from a map (Using Java 1.4)

Tags: java, java1.4

I am currently working on some old legacy application, and **must use Java 1.4** which has been EOL for several years now. I need to get a value from a map. My map looks like this:

```
Key     |  Value
---------------
String1 | int1
String2 | String6
String3 | Float1
String4 | String7
String5 | Object1
```

I tried the following, but I keep getting a null

```
String myVal = (String) map.get(String2);
```

Is it possible to get a value without using an Iterator?

Comment: If you get a null value out of that, it's because your map doesn't contain a key of `myString`. Note that the way you've shown it, you've got the same key 5 times... that doesn't sound likely. Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: If it's not a String, then you'll just get a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Hi Jon, I've edited the question for a clearer explanation. I don't have to worry about class cast exceptions as the keys are constants. I know what I am getting every time. Thank you both for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the value in the way you reported, this is totally right :

```
String myVal = (String) map.get("myKey");
```

As long as the map has that key inside.

The problem, with the map scheme you reported, is that the map could contain String, Float or other value types, so casting it directly to String is dangerous. You should check the value type :

```
Object myValObj = map.get("myKey");
if (myValObj instanceof String) {
  // Handle the string
} else if (myValObj instanceof Float) {
  // Handle the float
} // ....
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Simone, It turns out I was storing the values in my map as ""MyString"" and not "MyString". I guess I should get more sleep.